# Which exception should be raised when a required environment variable is missing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

The title pretty much sums it up already.

I have a piece of code that calls `os.getenv` to get both a URL as well as a token in order to connect to a service. The code lives in a module and will only be imported from there, i.e. it's not a script.

It's not a huge issue at all, since I really only need to crash and display the message saying that there are unset values, but it got me thinking about which of Python's built-in exceptions would be the best fit.

I found the `EnvironmentError`, but that seems to function as base class from which `IOError` and other OS related exceptions inherit.

Would it be as simple as a `ValueError`, as it's really just a value that's missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well most built in concrete exception classes are for specific use cases, and this one does not really fit in any but `RuntimeError`. But I would advise you to use a custom Exception subclass.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually looking to avoid creating my own exception. Batteries included and all that, I thought there surely has to be some built-in exception that fits. Oh well!

Comment: When you are accessing an env variable that does not exist in Python it will raise `ValueError` by default. See my answer.

Comment: I think you mean `KeyError`, right? In any case, I should have been more specific in my question. I'm accessing it through `os.getenv`, with no default value. Afterwards I'm performing the check and throw an error, if need be. Thanks anyway, I gave all of you well-deserved +1's :)

Comment: @TinNguyen: I assume that OP wants to filter the `ValueError` or access the environment in a way that does not throw it. But you are right on the `KeyError` point.

Comment: Yea `KeyError` my fault. The thing is you don't need to manually throw it since it is already thrown. It only makes sense to throw it if you have a custom logic for handling that error specifically. In which case it makes sense to raise your own custom error. So you can catch that error specifically. `KeyError` s are also raised when accessing a value from a dictionary through a key that does not exist. Those errors you might not want to catch since you might not have a way of handling those errors specifically.

Answer (score 11):

You can make your own exceptions for specific cases by inheriting from `Exception`

```
class MissingEnvironmentVariable(Exception):
    pass


def get_my_env_var(var_name):
    try:
        return os.environ[var_name]
    except KeyError:
        raise MissingEnvironmentVariable(f"{var_name} does not exist")
```

Comment: it's missing the 'return envvar'

Answer (score 8):

By default `KeyError` is already raised when an environment variable doesn't exist. `os.environ["THISENVDOESNTEXIST"]`

Furthermore you can supply a default variable if the env variable doesn't exist. Doing this won't raise the error. `os.environ.get("THISENVDOESNTEXIST", "defaultvalue")`

Code executed:

```
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.environ["THISENVDOESNTEXIST"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Tin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\os.py", line 678, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'THISENVDOESNTEXIST'
>>> os.environ.get("THISENVDOESNTEXIST", "defaultvalue")
'defaultvalue'
```

If you want to raise your own custom error you can do this:

```
class MyException(Exception):
  pass

try:
  os.environ["THISENVDOESNTEXIST"]
except KeyError as e:
  raise MyException("Tried accessing an environment variable that does not exist")
```

Answer (score 7):

You could always create a custom exception

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/user-defined-exception
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Ive used this guide before:

Something simple like

```py
class UnconfiguredEnvironment(Exception):
    """base class for new exception"""
    pass

if not os.environ.get("URL",None):
    raise UnconfiguredEnvironment
```

Use the guides to extend as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks! As I said in another comment I was hoping to avoid having to do that, but it does not matter much in the end. I just though surely there has to be a built-in one.

Comment: A great list to reference against is https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html